# Adding a PolygonCollider2D makes Unity instantly crash

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, collider

I've a problem with Unity3D : when I attach a PolygonCollider2D to some sprites the editor crashes immediately. It happens with some of the sprites ; it happens to all sprites derived from the same picture, but not with all pictures.  It happens indifferently wehter the collider is attached via script or manually via the editor. The crash seems to happen more frequently on reasonably large sprite images (like 512x512 or more).

It's the very same bug that was documented [here](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/adding-a-polygoncollider2d-to-a-sprite-hangs-unity) on Unity 4.3.1, and seemingly it still happens on Unity 5.4.3.

Is there a fix, or even a workaround ?

Comment: Unity 5.4.3 is really old. You should be using 2017 by now.

Comment: I just tried and can confirm that, this bug was corrected in Unity 2017. Thanks!

Comment: Great. I suspected that to be a bug